# PHP : check variables line by line in text file and store unique variables

Tags: php

I store my variables in text file.Next I get another vars, they most store in text file if they arent duplicate and old data must be clear.
Check each new vars by vars stored in file. and only store unique vars.

for example first I have:

```
hello
begin
start
all page
thanks
```

in text file and I get new vars :

```
buy
have
start
animate
hello
```

finally stored vars in text file must be:
    buy
    have
    animate

(ignored start & hello)

THXA

Comment: check new vars value with vars value stored in text file and return vars who not duplicate.

Comment: I wasn't clear. I meant to ask, what code have you produced so far, and how is it failing? Please provide the relevant sections of your code, and explain how it is operating differently than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is for file handling.

```
$myFile = "testFile1.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
```

Now, perform your comparison between the the data sets.